# Can't open url from inside Facebook instant game I made, does Facebook allow it

Tags: facebook-instant-games

I have a Facebook instant game and a button that opens an url
Testing locally, button works as expected: click button -> url is opened in a new tab

Testing on both Facebook web and Facebook instant games embedded test player, the button gives an error and the url isn't opened

```
Blocked opening [url] in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.
```

[image: error when opening an url]
Are Facebook instant games allowed to open urls at all ?

Answer (score 0):

You may able to edit any files for social media if you share the internet through your network and used the caching files and so you can edit them locally for those who are browsing them on your network .

In order to do that "allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" to the frame "attribute". This allows the sandboxed document to spawn new windows without forcing the sandboxing flags upon them, hence creating a clean browsing context. For example , a third-party advertisement could be safely sandboxed without forcing the same restrictions upon a landing page.

Popup windows can be spawned with window.open() and target="_blank" links.

```
<!-- No sandbox there... Popup window won't be sandboxed as well -->
<iframe id="red" src="iframe.html"></iframe>

<!-- This sandboxed frame will allow sandboxed popup window to open popups
 //but not to execute JavaScript for instance. -->
<iframe id="green" src="iframe.html" sandbox="allow-popups"></iframe>

<!-- This sandboxed frame will create a clean non sandboxed popup window,
 //allowed to execute JavaScript and open popups. -->
<iframe id="blue" src="iframe.html"
   // sandbox="allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like developers have any control over the iframe used for the games

Comment: unless you are loading the internet websites from caching server yes I agree with you :) … so think about what am saying and try the above